# Check if main server resolving from file server

Tags: domain-name-system

I have a main server and a file server, how can I verify the main server is resolving from the file server?

Thanks

extra info :

Alright, so I have my main site just on a simple server, nothing big. Now I have a separate server (server 2) to store the files on. The thing is, server 2 isn't being able to see server 1. Is there a way I can try to ping server 1 from ssh on server 2 or something?

Comment: You're going to have to clarify this a *whole lot.* Like, what operating systems are they? What is a "main server"? What sharing protocol is the file server using (NFS, SMB)? What do you mean by "resolving" ?

Comment: As suggesed by mfinni, you need to clarify your question to get help!

Comment: Voted to close. Your edit is at least as vague as the original question and you didn't answer any of the three questions that I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very precise question, but I try to provide the best answer in this unfavorable situation :)

`nslookup main.server.fully.qualified.domain.name. file.server.fully.qualified.domain.name.`

This should work on UNIX and even on this funny MS systems.

Comment: If you don't have DNS server, try `dig a main.server.fully.qualified.domain.name.` being on file server.